# Call recorder is not working on android 4.1.2

Tags: android, mediarecorder, audiorecord

Call Recorder is recording on most of the devices but not working on samsung grand. Means recording is started on incoming or outgoing and records the sound from the selected source (mic etc) but further device will stop to record the sound (could be the reason the recorder is not getting data from that source in in-call(Android's user privacy issue)).

I have tried AudioRecord and MediaRecorder for this but the problem remains unsolved.

```
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    recorder.setAudioSource(1);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(1);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(1);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
```

also i tried audiorecord but it is not working for this issue.

Comment: Is your problem solved? I have also facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

I will post a code for question.This code is working perfectly in my application

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

```
    mSampleFile = null;
    if (mSampleFile == null) {

        String newFolder = "/Recording";

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);

        if (!myNewFolder.exists()) {

            myNewFolder.mkdir();

        }

        try {

            if (myNewFolder != null) {

                mSampleFile = File.createTempFile(SAMPLE_PREFIX,
                        SAMPLE_EXTENSION, myNewFolder);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    if (mSampleFile != null) {
        SharedPreferences mysharedprefs8 = getSharedPreferences(mypref32,
                MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        String status = mysharedprefs8.getString("pass", "AMR_NB");

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("AMR")) {
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("MPEG")) {
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("3GPP")) {
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        } else {
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        }
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {

            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mSampleFile.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000);
        try {

            mRecorder.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        mRecorder.start();
        mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.reset();
                    mRecorder.release();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: But source MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL is not working on most of the devices i think android is not permitted to record user's voice calls.

Comment: You have add system level premisses in your manifest file. Then you will be able to record the voice calls.

Comment: But it always shows "Permission is only granted to system apps". See we can record uplink and downlink as source so we have to try that which is permitted on all the devices but problem is that 4.1.2 started the recording but further not getting any data from source and recording duration is increasing then stop the recording on call.

Comment: i have done the recording in this way into 4.1 android version.

Comment: Yas you are right. I tested my app in HTC one that does not record voice.